# Showing a webpage based on the time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html form which I want to be open between 12:00am and 4:20pm, after 4:20 I want to close the form and show a 'This form is now closed'. This needs to happen daily. What can I use to set the time and re-direct the users based on the time? Is this a j-query thing?

Comment: You can use jquery to make the form disappear on the client's side, but you'll also need to disable it on your server. What server language are you using?

Comment: This feature is better implemented on server side. It's quite easy to hack the JavaScript code on the browser to access the form on restricted time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adriancarriger/dgg49j9t/1/)

This will close the form at the correct time without requiring you to reload the page.

### HTML

```
<form id="my-form" style="display:none">
    <label>Name: <input type="text" ></label>
</form>
<div id="form-closed" style="display:none">The form is now closed</div>
```

### Javascript/jQuery

```
checkFormAvailability();

setInterval(function(){
    checkFormAvailability();
}, 1000);

function checkFormAvailability() {
    var minHours = 0;
    var minMinutes = 0;
    var maxHours = 16;
    var maxMinutes = 20;

    var minHourMinutes = (minHours * 100) + minMinutes;
    var maxHourMinutes = (maxHours * 100) + maxMinutes;
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getHours() * 100;
    var m = d.getMinutes();
    var currentHourMinutes = n + m;
    if (currentHourMinutes >= minHourMinutes && currentHourMinutes <= maxHourMinutes) {
        $('#my-form').show();
        $('#form-closed').hide();
    }
    else {
       $('#my-form').hide();
       $('#form-closed').show();
    }
}
```

To test it out you can change `maxHours` and `maxMinutes` to the current time, and it will close the form starting in the next minute.

Answer (score 0):

Everytime they visit/update the page, you can have a JavaScript function run and do different things based on the hour and minute.

For example:

```
<head>
<script>
  function changeForm() {
    var d = new Date();
    if(d.getHours() == 16) {
      if(d.getMinutes() > 19 {
        document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('myMessage').innerHTML = "The form is now closed.";
       }
    }
    if(d.getHours() > 16) {
      document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById('myMessage').innerHTML = "The form is now closed.";
    }               
 }

</script>
</head>

<body onload = changeForm()>
 ...
</body>
```